# Working with SCHEDULED items (recurring task), org mode

Tags: org-mode

When I schedule an item, I want to get something like:

```
** TODO Lift weights
   SCHEDULED: <2009-01-22 Thu +2d> 
   - State "DONE"       [2009-01-16 Fri 23:14]
   - State "DONE"       [2009-01-14 Wed 17:25]
```

I suppose the state update for something like `SCHEDULED: <2015-10-07 Tue>--<2015-10-17 Tue>` would be the same.

The scheduling as such looks OK in the org-agenda (something like `myfile: (1/11): TODO Lift weights`.

However, how does the "- State "DONE" ..." part get inserted? What function or key-biding generate these lines (when the time comes)? How do I keep track of partial tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The insertion of the `- State "DONE"...` is mostly controlled by the variable `org-log-done`, which causes org-mode to insert a timestamp when a entry is changed to a done state.  You can also control this per-state by adding a `(!)` to the definition of the state in `org-todo-keywords`.

Whether the note is appended to the entry of placed in the `LOGBOOK` drawer is controlled by the `org-log-into-drawer` variable or the `LOG_INTO_DRAWER` property.